# How to modify SmsManager?

Tags: android

I would like to modify SmsManager to have it be able to accept a context.
Can i do this? If yes, how can i?

Answer (score 1):

SmsManager is part of the telephony library. I wouldn't recommend extending this directly since they tend to lock down these parts of the system. What I can recommend is just creating your own wrapper class that has an SmsManager and Context variable inside. Then you can expose an interface to achieve whatever your trying to do.

Comment: How can i achive this? I would like anyone who use SmsManager to use mystuff.

Comment: Aww. Well your not going to be able to highjack SmsManager if that's what your thinking. But if you create an Android Library Project (google that) then other cans link to it and use your class to interface with the default SmsManager along with your additional functionality. Good luck.